# Can the Web 8.5 deployer endpoint be load balanced?

Tags: deployer, web8.5, load-balancing

I recently attended the SDL Web 8.5 bootcamp where we learned about the scaled out deployer with multiple workers.

My question is - is it possible to load balance the deployer endpoint to create a High Availability deployer? I have a diagram which implies you can but I don't see it on the list of load-balancable services here: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-73331A57-BA35-442E-8C10-ECC96C25B44A

Comment: For reference, here are the details on scaling out the Deployer: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-EC2E2703-3FA6-44B5-AB9A-2B1A817FD454

Comment: Thanks Jon but that is adding multiple workers, what I want to know is can you have two Deployer Endpoint microservices in an active/active load balanced scenario - previously the only possible configuration as active/passive which basically wasted a CD CPU licence!

Comment: Yep. Got that. The link I posted was just as a reference point (for everyone else) for your comment in the first paragraph about scaling out the Deployer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed possible to have a load balanced deployer endpoint. However this does require the Queue/BinaryStorage to be of the distributed type. Meaning for the Queue a JMS based implementation and for the BinaryStorage a NFS based storage or Redis. However in case you want to scale-out your workers you would need this anyway.

Comment: Just to clarify - I assume that means that you couldn't active/active loadbalance a Deployer-combined role?

Comment: You could do this on a combined role if you so desire, but it does still require the JMS Queue to be used. The problem is that you cannot have multiple queue producer/consumers using the FS Queue implementation even if they on the same system which is the default the combined will use. So you need to switch that to JMS based queue.